# is it mandatory to have if-else block at same corresponding level(one below other) in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, indentation

I am a python newbie and I have a confusion in writing this if-else block with correct indentation. I read that if-else block should appear at same corresponding level(one below other)however when I was writing a code block, the code block still worked by giving me the output. So, my question is that is it mandatory to write if-else code block at same corresponding vertical level(one below other)? if No, then can you explain, how does the logic flow in the below code?
The code gives the prime number within a list.

```
h=9
a=[]
for i in range(2,h):
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i%j==0:
                break
        else:
            a.append(i)
```

The above code worked without having the correct indentation.

Comment: Note that `for` loops can have an `else` clause.

Comment: thanks a lot , for clarifying the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes indention is mandatory.

Maybe you can try [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) so you can attempt your code in a single line.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering but ,If indentation is mandatory then how did the above code worked or simply got compiled without having the indentation?